# How to limit showing of a block just in home page?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I have a library book and in the first page or homepage of my website I want to show just 4 random books in center of my page.

How to set a View block to just show in home page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by following below way :

1. After creating Views Block.
2. Goto Admin -> Structure -> Blocks (Search your block)
3. Configure -> Your block
4. Goto *Pages* section. Click on *"Only the listed pages"* & write **`<front>`** & Save block.